# Check if record exists in Django Rest Framework API LIST/DATABASE

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a viewset/apiview with a path like this: `list/<slug:entry>/` that once I provide the `entry` it will check if that entry exists in the database.

*Note: on `list/` I have a path to a `ViewSet`. I wonder if I could change the id with the specific field that I want to check, so I could see if the entry exists or not, but I want to keep the id as it is, so

I tried:

```
class CheckCouponAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            Coupon.objects.get(coupon=self.kwargs.get('coupon'))
        except Coupon.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(data={'message': False})
        else:
            return Response(data={'message': True})
```

But I got an error: `get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coupon'`.

Here's the path: `path('check/<slug:coupon>/', CheckCouponAPIView.as_view()),`

Is there any good practice that I could apply in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about trying something like this,

```
class CheckCouponAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # other fields
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

From the official [DRF Doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/),

> `lookup_field` - The model field that should be used to for performing
>   object lookup of individual model instances. Defaults to `pk`

Comment: I tried it on Serializer for whatever reason. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to do it elsewhere because it can be done with just `lookup_field`  and it's more simplified